# Replacing outlier values in R

Tags: r, replace, outliers

I need a way to replace outliers with the value -9999.  In my data -9999 means the value is missing.  This is just a convention typically used for this type of data instead of NA

I have a data frame called amf that is 43 columns.  I need to go column by column and replace each value above the 99 percentile and the below the 1 percentile with -9999.  Some columns I need to skip though, such as the day of year column.

I have tried using the apply and lapply functions in various ways but I must be using them incorrectly.  Here is what I have tried

```
amf_out <- apply(amf[,4:43],2, which(amf[,4:43] > quantile(amf[,4:43, .99)))

amf_out <- lapply(1:length(amf), function(i) amf[which(amf[,i] > quantile(amf[,1],.99))] <- 
-9999)

amf[which(amf[,4:43] > quantile(amf[,4:43], .99))] <- -9999
```

None of theses have worked.  Any suggestions?

Comment: What is your justification for doing this? Depending on your setting/data, this can be highly unethical.

Comment: I agree with rawr. If you want to remove outliers you should at the very least use a proper outlier test. However, you shouldn't do this at all.

Comment: This is data from weather instruments.  Occasionally the instrument may malfunction and record values way outside an acceptable range, such as 1000 C for temperture.  Any values that are clearly unacceptable need to all be set to one value that is designated the missing value.

Comment: But then you shouldn't do this based on the quantiles, but define a temperature range that is meteorologically possible.

Comment: What is a better function to remove the extreme values?

Answer (score 1):

When you are working in R, use `NA` for missing values.  Anything else will create coding headaches and be a source of bugs.  You should only use a different missing value when exporting data for use with other software that requires such a different value.  `write.table` (and its variants like `write.csv`) have an `na` argument that let's you specify this value.

```
write.csv(amf_out, "my file", na = "-9999")
```

Answer (score 1):

Leaving aside whether you should do this or not, here is another alternative:

```
threshold <- 1000
as.data.frame(lapply(amf_out, function(x) replace(x, x > threshold, -9999)))
```

Here, you go column by column and replace the values that exceed your threshold.  Presumably you want the same threshold for all the values.  It can be `1000`, or a quantile, or whatever.

Answer (score 0):

To get an output data.frame, you can use the following:

`amf_out <- apply(amf[,4:43],2, function(x) {x[x > quantile(x, .99) & x < quantile(x, .01)] <- -9999;x})`